# Changing multiple colors of an image using Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to change 2 colors of an image
The white should be one color and black should be another

The image I am trying to change

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgOM9.png

My thinking is `p` is the RGB color value, so if it is less than 200, it should be black, and above 200 should be white

The resulting image looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGHTK.png

As you can see it changes the white but not the black

I cannot figure it for the life of me, any advice to what im doing wrong would be much appreciated

The function

```
var src = getChangeColorImgSrc2('#F8931D', '#008000', ctx);

function getChangeColorImgSrc2(hex1, hex2, ctx)
{
    if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
    var newColor = hexToRGB(hex1);
    var newColor2 = hexToRGB(hex2);

    for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
    {
        var p = currentPixels.data[I + 3];

        if(p > 0 && p < 200) // If it's not a transparent pixel
        {
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
        }
        else if(p > 200)
        {
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor2.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor2.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor2.B;
        }
    }


    ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `p` when it is a black pixel? If it's 0, neither condition will be true

Comment: Actually disregard my last comment, your are fine there. I'm just not fully awake yet. It seems likely it's what @SlashmanX mentioned.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line 'originalPixels.data[I] / 255' ?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes - here you go https://jsfiddle.net/2rrhk0vc/1/

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate black to be a colour due to black being #000, what you need to do is if the colour is black do not use `originalPixels.data`, just straight up use `newColor2` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is essentially calculating the percent of white in the original color (i.e. originalColor.R / 255) and then taking that percent of the new color.

When attempting to convert white to new color, you logic works because...

```
= originalColor.R / 255 * newColor.R
= 255 / 255 * newColor.R
= 1 * newColor.R
= newColor.R
```

When attempting to convert black to new color, your logic fails because...

```
= originalColor.R / 255 * newColor2.R
= 0 / 255 * newColor2.R
= 0 * newColor2.R
= 0
```

To convert black to new color, you need to calculate the percent of black in the original color (i.e. (255 - original.R) / 255) and then take that percent of the new color.

```
= (255 - originalColor.R) / 255 * newColor2.R
= (255 - 0) / 255 * newColor2.R
= 255 / 255 * newColor2.R
= 1 * newColor2.R
= newColor2.R
```

You can also simplify your code by elimating the if statement and just adding the percents of the two new colors. This will handle converting grays (which are a mix of white and black) to a mix of the two new colors.

In your getChangeColorImgSrc2() function, change...

```
for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
{
    var p = currentPixels.data[I + 3];
    if(p > 0 || p < 200) // If it's not a transparent pixel
    {
        currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
        currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
        currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
    }
    else if(p > 0 || p > 200)
    {
        currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor2.R;
        currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor2.G;
        currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor2.B;
    }
}
```

to...

```
for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
{
    currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R + (255 - originalPixels.data[I]) / 255 * newColor2.R;
    currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G + (255 - originalPixels.data[I + 1]) / 255 * newColor2.G;
    currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B + (255 - originalPixels.data[I + 2]) / 255 * newColor2.B;
}
```

Comment: It's almost there, here is the image now https://gyazo.com/f418bc09f384009f209fdf83e3689fda

Comment: But it's meant to change the white to orange, and black to green not the outline